# Expressing $\sum_{k=1}^3(A_k\cos(x-\alpha_k)-C_k)^2$ in the form $A\cos(x-\alpha)+B$

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics, sums-of-squares

I have the following sum
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^3  (A_k \cos(x - \alpha_k) - C_k)^2$$
which I want to bring into the form
$$f(x) = A\cos(x - \alpha) + B$$
I know I can rewrite with the squares the entire expression to
$$f(x) = A^*\cos^2(x - \alpha_k) + B^*\cos(x - \alpha_k) + C^*$$
with constants, $A^*, B^*, C^*$, but I'm unsure how they are connected to the start equation.
How could I solve this?

I want to bring it into the form described as part of a proof.

Comment: In general this sum is not a cosine function.  For instance $\cos^2 x + \cos x$ can not be written in the desired form.  Is there additional information?

Comment: No there isn't, but that it could be written in the cosine form was just my thought (and as it looks wrong).